# Word for "wide variety of"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'd like to reduce the sentence "The product is used by a wide variety of people, such as jugglers, priests, and businessmen" in length.

Thus, I'm looking for a word that would replace "a wide range of". The first thing I thought of was "various", but it doesn't seem to convey the same meaning when I say "used by various people" rather than "used by a wide variety of people". Any ideas as to what word would go there?

Comment: I have an aversion to wide, variety, various, multitude in places like the CV (*No, you worked on 5 of the **same** project!*) But I could live with "The product is used widely, from jugglers to priests."

Comment: Both "array" and "range" imply "wide variety" and are shorter by a little bit, although you have to keep the "a" (or "an") before and the "of" after either word.

Comment: You could just say, “The product is used by people from jugglers to priests, from businessmen (oops! sexist) to animal trainers.   Phrases like “from soup to nuts.”

Answer (score 2):

***[Diverse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diverse)*** conveys a meaning close to what you are looking for:

> composed of distinct or unlike elements or qualities:
> *a diverse population*

(M-W)

Comment: doesn't "used by diverse people, such as ..." seem awkward?

Comment: @user760900 - “technologies, used by diverse people, in diverse real-world locations” https://books.google.it/books?id=5i83DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22used+by+diverse+people%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr3YvsvJLvAhWKDOwKHQ1aDKQQ6AEwAHoECAAQAw#v=onepage&q=%22used%20by%20diverse%20people%22&f=false

Comment: @user760900 - “language that may be used by diverse people in diverse settings and different times...” https://books.google.it/books?id=vU76CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT45&dq=%22used+by+diverse+people%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq5cWTvZLvAhUCuaQKHWTOCPwQ6AEwAXoECAAQAw#v=onepage&q=%22used%20by%20diverse%20people%22&f=false

Comment: Diverse can now 'feature' BAMEs and LGBTQ, amongst others?

Answer (score 1):

[Various](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/various) *is* a valid possibility. The online Cambridge dictionary defines "various" as

> many different

with examples:

> We had various problems on our journey, including a flat tyre.
> The author gave various reasons for having written the book.
> Girardo was out of action with various injuries for most of last season.
> Various people whom we weren't expecting turned up at the meeting.

The same dictionary gives the alternative US definition

> several and different

With examples:

> He underwent various treatments for the disease, none of them successful.
> We enjoy eating in various types of restaurants.
> After holding various jobs in different states, he settled in Oregon and opened a law office in Portland.

Using 'various' in your sentence would give

*The product is used by **various** people, such as jugglers, priests, and businessmen*

Given the above definitions this carries the idea of the people being different from each other.

Comment: Right, but I may as well say "various people such as juggler #1, juggler #2, and juggler #3". I'm trying to convey the idea that it covers some spectrum of people and not just 3 different people.

Comment: The word 'various' primarily means a heterogeneous group. The fact that it is sometimes used for a somewhat homogeneous group doesn't negate that. By giving your heterogeneous examples you confirm the meaning of 'various' that you wish to convey.

Answer (score 0):

'This **all-encompassing** product is used by jugglers, priests and businessmen, **amongst others**

'This **all-encompassing** product is used by jugglers, priests and businessmen **alike**.

All-encompassing: including or covering everything or everyone; comprehensive.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=all+encompassing